# SQL - Retrieving Data from two related tables based on a value entered by a user

Tags: c#, sql, database, join

I am trying to get data from two separate but related tables (They have a foreign key between them) based on the value that the user enters. If the value is entered into `textBox11` for example, my SQL statement is:

```
SQLCommandText = "select Invoice_Name.Inv_Nu, Invoice_Name.Price, Invoice_Name.IDate, AddInfo.Case_Nu, AddInfo.PaperName, AddInfo.Page_Nu, AddInfo.Case_Type, AddInfo.Size from Invoice_Name full outer join AddInfo on Invoice_Name.L_Name = " + "'" + textBox11.Text + "'";
```

This doesn't seem to work properly, I can't seem to find out why.

The two tables I have are:

```
Invoice_Name
------------
Inv_Nu
L_Name
Price
IDate

AddInfo
-------
Inv_Nu
Case_Nu
PaperName
PageNumber
Case_Type
Size
```

I want the user to enter the `L_Name` and the program to bring back all the info in BOTH tables where the L_Name is equal to that value. The foreign key here is the Inv_Nu taken from the Invoice_Name table.

Test data:

```
Invoice_Name: 
Inv_Nu | L_Name | Price | IDate
01064 | Rami Isleem | 215 | 19/6/2013

AddInfo:
Inv_Nu | Case_Nu | PaperName | Page_Nu | Case_Type | Size
01064 | 100/20 | Alra'i | 21 | abc | 2x8
```

Comment: Please tell us what exactly happens! Are you receiving an error? Is the resultset empty? Is it imcomplete? Are you checking cases? And be warned: This opens a lot of potential SQL Injection stuff!!!

Comment: Unless you can explain why you have a full outer join, change it to an inner join.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but still important: *Use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injections!!!*

Comment: It seems to return ALL the data from my tables

Comment: user parameters, you will have peace.

Answer (score 2):

You have to join the 2 tables on `Inv_NU` and filter on `Invoice_Name.L_Name = textBox11.Text`:

```
"select Invoice_Name.Inv_Nu, Invoice_Name.Price, Invoice_Name.IDate, 
        AddInfo.Case_Nu, AddInfo.PaperName, AddInfo.Page_Nu, 
        AddInfo.Case_Type, AddInfo.Size 
   from Invoice_Name 
   left join AddInfo on Invoice_Name.Inv_NU = AddInfo.Inv_NU
  where Invoice_Name.L_Name = " + "'" + textBox11.Text + "'";
```

Instead of `FULL OUTER JOIN`, use a `LEFT JOIN` because you're filtering `Invoice_Name` rows then joining `AddInfo` rows.

Comment: Try to execute it directly in the database with a `L_Name` value you know it should return results.

Comment: Empty result set even directly from the database :S

Comment: And what should the result be?

Comment: A bunch of values, one for each of the columns I stated above.. Random test values that I inserted just to test the sql statements on.

Comment: Paste those test rows, and the result you want for a L_Name of your choice in your question, then it should be easy to find a solution.

Comment: Ok, one test row is:

Invoice_Name:
Inv_Nu: 01064
L_Name: Rami Isleem
Price: 215
IDate 19/6/2013

AddInfo
Inv_Nu: 01064
Case_Nu: 100/20
PaperName: Alra'i

Comment: Page_Nu: 21
Case_Type: abc
Size: 2x8

Comment: Those are the results I should get when I enter "Rami Isleem" as the value for L_Name

Comment: Tested and works as expected. See results in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58c2c/1).

Comment: Yes, I see... Same code to the letter, but won't work :S Anyway, thank you.